# Formula “=''Sheet 1''!A1” does not work with writer Excel2007 in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a problem with writer excel2007 of PHPExcel. The formular get value from another sheet name does not work. The following is my code.

```
$xfile = new PHPExcel();
$xfile->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet1 = $xfile->getActiveSheet();
$sheet1->setTitle('Sheet 1');
$sheet1->setCellValue('A1', 100);

$xfile->createSheet();
$sheet2 = $xfile->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$sheet2->setCellValue('A1', "='Sheet 1'!A1");
$sheet2->setTitle('Sheet 2');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xfile, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('test.xlsx');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xfile, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('test.xls');
```

In above script, I generate 2 files: test.xlsx and test.xls

In file test.xls, value of A1 of Sheet 2 is 100

But in file test.xlsx, value of A1 of Sheet 2 is 0

=> Right value is 100

Is there any way to use this formular in Excel2007?

Note: I open 2 files by Libre Office Calc. I am not sure that how is it if I open by MS Excel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are sending the http response headers ***after*** you are sending the output to the browser. This will result in all manner of problems, such as "headers already set".

The same should apply equally whatever Writer you are using.... send the headers ***before*** you save the spreadsheet to `php://output`

If you send the headers first, then this code works exactly as expected

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I have edited my code as above. The issue is that in sheet 2 of excel, A1 cell is not equal 100 as A1 of sheet 1.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this myself, using your code as posted here (with the fix that I said in my answer), and it works exactly as expected.... so tell me what you are getting in A1 of sheet 2?